# .NET's "InternalsVisibleTo" equivalent in Haskell

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, internalsvisibleto

In .NET I can decorate my assembly with the following attribute:

```ml
[<assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Test")>]
```

Thanks to this, all the modules marked as "internal" are accessible from "MyProject.Test". I can use it e.g. for unit testing the functionality I don't want to expose in my library.

I'm wondering if there's something similar in the Haskell's world. Let's say I have a library with the following .cabal file:

```
library
  exposed-modules:  MyLibrary.API
  other-modules:    MyLibrary.Utils
  -- ...

test-suite mylib-test
  -- ...
  build-depends:  base,
                  hspec,
                  my-library
```

Is there a way to refer to "MyLibrary.Utils" from mylib-test test-suite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it part of an internal library, and depend on that from both the public library and the test suite. It will not be available outside the package.

```
library utils
    exposed-modules: MyLibrary.Utils

library
    exposed-modules: MyLibrary.API
    build-depends: utils

test-suite mylib-test
    build-depends: base, hspec, my-library, utils
```

Alternately, there's a strong convention of exposing the module anyway, but including `Internal` in its name and telling folks in the documentation that you break it you bought it.

Comment: Sounds legit. I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite new to the world of Haskell, so I don't know the conventions. If you say it's a strong one, then I guess it's better to follow it, isn't it? :)

Comment: @AlojzyLeszcz Be the change you want to see in the world. That's why I use metric exclusively despite living in the US. (That said it's not clear to me that internal libraries are the obviously superior choice. There is something interesting about being given the power to tinker with internals when the situation calls for it -- and there's also something interesting about never having to deal with complaints from folks that depended on internals and got upset when they changed.)

Comment: I think it would be good to note that internal libraries don’t quite have complete support yet — I believe `stack` can’t be used with them. So personally I won’t be using internal libraries until `stack` gains support for them.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've given it a go and created another library in my .cabal file. It works well, the only problem I have now is that ```cabal new-haddock``` attempts to generate a documentation for the ```utils``` library as well. Is there a way to instruct it to create doc only for the main library?

Comment: @AlojzyLeszcz Ah, hm. I'm not sure if there's a cabal way, but haddock has tools for telling it which modules to generate docs for, and even a way to tell which module should be the "home" module for an exported symbol (i.e. if multiple modules export a symbol, which one should other mentions link to). There's detailed instructions in the haddock user manual.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at cabal and haddock docs.